Shadows not showing in render
Object don't create shadow when rendering.
Video link: https://streamable.com/afwqxn
blend file: 

Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload images or gifs, along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

hello maybe your object is invisible for render? Hard to thell without the file...

@mooboots Now it´s available

The light that is doing to cast shadow, is too big in comparison to fan:

In this case, shadow will be too blurred to be visible.
The reason why you see the shadow in animation preview is simple. During animation playback, Blender cast only one sample for shadows, so that it is not possible to calculate soft shadows. Then you stop playback or hit render, Blender calculates more samples for shadow and it blurs out.
Solution #1:
Make light source smaller, like this:

Solution #2:
Use Blender 4.2. It uses new algorithms to calculate soft shadows, so that they visible enough even with so big light source:
Render:

Playback:


It worked. Thank you
